# Show g is unbounded above if g and g' are increasing

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $g$ is a function defined on the set of real numbers where $g(y)$, $g'(y)$, and $g''(y)$ are all greater than $0$ for all $y \in \mathbb R$. Show that $g$ is unbounded above as $y$ approaches ∞.

I know that $g$ and $g'$ are strictly increasing since $g'$ and $g''$ are greater than $0$, but I am having trouble with the rest of the reasoning.

Comment: Remember that $\;g''>0\implies g\;$ is convex upwards, and this together with $\;g\;$ being increasing given unboundness.

Comment: How could I write this out in a proof then, can it be shown we get a convex upward function using a theorem such as the Mean Value Theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Let $a := g'(0) >0$. Because $g'$ is increasing, this yields $g'(x)\geq g'(0)=a$ for all $x \geq 0$.

What does this imply for $g$?

Remark: This argument does not use $g>0$ and only needs $g''\geq 0$.

Comment: I think with this argument you could show $g(x)-g(0)> xg'(0)$ by integrals, is this where you were going with it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You get $g( x) \geq g(0)+x g'(0)$ for $x \geq 0$. This follows either by integration or by using the mean value theorem.

Comment: So how does this follow from the mean value theorem? I saw it through integrals not through that theorem.

Comment: By the mean value theorem, there is some $\xi \in (0,x)$ with $(g( x)-g(0))/(x-0) = g'(\xi)\geq g'(0)$. Now rearrange.

Comment: And so g(x) diverges, that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: One comment: If you receive helpful answers to your question, you can accept it (the most helpful one), by using the green "checkmark" button. This will keep people motivated to answer your questions :) [I noted that you did not do that for any of your questions]. Of course, if no answer is helpful, it is ok to not accept any.